# Safari strange behaviour with Range header

Tags: http, safari, range

Safari loading not valid range of binary data. You can see it on screenshot. I think it somehow connected with cache. Because first attempt always correct. Works perfect in other browsers.
See Range in request and Range in response.

[image: Screenshot from debug console]

Comment: What's the problem with the *request*?

Comment: The problem is that i requested bytes from 155028-164144 but received bytes from 153660-155027. Which was requested in a previous request.

Comment: But then it's a strange behavior of the server, not Safari, right?

Comment: No, it isn't right. Because server is nginx with standart configuration. Because Range header is a standart header for nginx. And this request works well in all other browsers. (tested in IE, Mozilla, Chrome) And if i ask server with cleared cache in safari it works correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request isn't coming to the http server. So the problem is in the safari cache implementation which caches range requests without checking bytes.